# Pandas covert nan values to None in string list before literal_eval and convert back to np.nan

Tags: python, pandas, nan, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a dataframe with a few series that contain lists of floats that includes nan values. Eg.

```
s[0] = '[1.21, 1.21, nan, nan, 100]'
```

These strings I want to convert to lists using `literal_eval`. When I try I get the error `ValueError: malformed node or string on line 1:` because as per the docs, `nan` values cannot be converted as these values are not recognised.

What is the best way of converting the `nan` values within the string, to `None` and then converting back to `np.nan` values after applying `literal_eval`?

Comment: Why is necessary convert `None` to `np.nan` ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I think working with nan values is best with pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is like described in a question, but you get `None`s instead `NaN`s:

```
s.str.replace('nan', 'None', regex=True).apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

If you need `np.nan`s use custom function:

```
def convert(x):
    out = []
    for y in x.strip('[]').split(', '):
        try:   
           out.append(ast.literal_eval(y))
        except:
           out.append(np.nan)
    return out

s.apply(convert)
```

Another idea would be to convert all values to floats:

```
f = lambda x: [float(y) for y in x.strip('[]').split(', ')]
s.apply(f)
```

---

```
pd.Series([[float(y) for y in x.strip('[]').split(', ')] for x in s], 
              index=s.index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapting jezrael's answer, a one-liner to incorporate converting a series of lists nan to None, converting to list using literal_eval and back to nan is:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace('nan', 'None', regex=True).apply(ast.literal_eval).apply(lambda row: [np.nan if x is None else x for x in row])
```